# LINQ-All condition

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a Class :

```
Public Class Task
{
    Public Guid TaskId { get ; set }
    Public Guid ParentId { get ; set }
    ...
}
```

And Another class :

```
Public Class ContractDetail
{
    Public Guid ContractDetailsID {get;set}
    Public Guid TaskId { get;set}
    ...
}
```

I want to check if all Tasks have ContractDetail then do some thing and I wrote this query:

```
 List<Guid> Sids = new List<Guid>();
 Sids = Tasks.Where(p => p.ParentId == ParentId).Select(p => p.TaskId).ToList();
 if(ContractDetails.All(p => Sids.Contains(p.TaskId))
 {
      int i = 5;
      .....
 }
```

But it returns false always.

How to check All of Tasks have ContractDetails or not?

Comment: How about using **TrueForAll**

Comment: I replaced All with TrueForAll and it returns false , It think the problem is using Contains condition.

Comment: Don't you need to compare it by using the **ToString()** ?

Comment: It's not very clear... let me rephrase: you want to check that *for each Task, there is at least one ContractDetail*, right ?

Comment: I want to check that all of tasks have at least one contractdetial or not . If one task dosen't have any contract detail it must return false,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
bool allTasksHaveContractDetails = Tasks.All(t => ContractDetails.Any(cd => cd.TaskId == t.TaskId))
```

Another approach:

```
var query =
    from t in Tasks
    join cd in ContractDetails on t.TaskId equals cd.TaskId into tmp
    select tmp;

bool allTasksHaveContractDetails = query.All(x => x.Any());
```

Comment: Tnx for your good response But because I want to check a list of children I changed it to it : Sids.All(y => ContractDetails.Any(cd => cd.TaskId == y))

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Contains, try:

```
Sids.Any(s => s.Equals(p.SakhtarId))
```

And try to debug it by making sure that this condition should really be true.

Comment: I confused , I want to compare on Tasks not on child list.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I fully get your usage scenario, but assuming you want to check that for every `Task` there is an associated `ContractDetail`, i.e. the `ContractDetail` and the `Task` have the same `TaskId`, you can select the unique ids from both collections and use `IEnumerable.SequenceEquals` like so:

```
var tids = tasks.OrderBy(t => t.TaskId).Select(t => t.TaskId).Distinct();
var ctids = details.OrderBy(c => c.TaskId).Select(c => c.TaskId).Distinct();

if (tids.SequenceEqual(ctids))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Every task has a contract");
}
```

Comment: Tnx it's ok but I think that there is a better solution because may be 2 list have many members and compare of to list isn't very good at this point.

Comment: It's faster than for *every* element of `Tasks` going over `ContractDetails` and looking for a matching `TaskId`.